# MASM32 error A2070: invalid instruction operands

Tags: assembly, masm32

I have an assembly32 code for Hanoi, but I can't compile it, i get the error:
hanoi.asm(9) : error A2070: invalid instruction operands
I use MASM32.

The full code:

```
        .586
.MODEL  FLAT
PUBLIC        _towers
EXTERN  _printf:NEAR
.CODE
_towers:PUSH  EBP
        MOV   EBP, ESP
        SUB   ESP, 4
        CMP   [EBP+8], 1   ;ERROR
        JNE   L1
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+16]
        PUSH  EAX
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+12]
        PUSH  EAX
        PUSH  OFFSET FLAT:format;
        CALL  _printf
        ADD   ESP, 12
        JMP   Done
L1:     MOV   EAX, 6
        SUB   EAX, [EBP+12]
        SUB   EAX, [EBP+16]
        MOV   [EBP-4], EAX
        PUSH  EAX
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+12]
        PUSH  EAX
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+8]
        DEC   EAX
        PUSH  EAX
        CALL  _towers
        ADD   ESP, 12
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+16]
        PUSH  EAX
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+12]
        PUSH  EAX
        PUSH   1
        CALL   _towers
        ADD   ESP,12
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+16]
        PUSH  EAX
        MOV   EAX, [EBP-4]
        PUSH  EAX
        MOV   EAX, [EBP+8]
        DEC   EAX
        PUSH  EAX
        CALL  _towers
        ADD   ESP, 12
Done:   MOV   ESP,EBP
        POP   EBP
        RET   0
.DATA
format  DB "Move from %d to %d\n"
END
```

Can you please help me, how can I make this work?

Comment: It's unclear what the data size is. Use `cmp dword ptr [ebp+8], 1`.

Comment: Are you sure this is all the code? Hanoi towers require a starting point for the three discs, this code starts so sudden, without any data been initialized. The algorithm is not working for me, I mean, it doesn't solve the hanoi problem.

Comment: As you can see in my answer, the code is using 16 bit registers, and it works fine. You can change all the 16 bit registers for 32 bit (AX -> EAX), and test it to see if it stills work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code didn't work for me, I ran it but something is wrong with the algorithm, it never found the solution.

So, here is another hanoi towers solution that actually works. It's made with EMU8086 (MASM Intel syntax), you just copy-paste and run :

```
.model small
.stack 300H
.data
x dw 3
text db "Move from peg "
d1 db ?
text2 db " to peg "
d2 db ?
newline db 0AH, 0DH, '$'

.code
main proc

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ax, 1
    push ax
    mov ax, 3
    push ax
    mov ax, 2
    push ax
    mov ax, x
    push ax
    call solve

    mov ax, 4C00H
    int 21h


main endp

solve proc
   push bp
   mov bp, sp
   cmp word ptr ss:[bp+4], 0
   je down

   push word ptr ss:[bp+0AH]
   push word ptr ss:[bp+6]
   push word ptr ss:[bp+8]
   mov ax, word ptr ss:[bp+4]
   dec ax
   push ax
   call solve

   push word ptr ss:[bp+0AH]
   push word ptr ss:[bp+08]
   call print

   push word ptr ss:[bp+06H]
   push word ptr ss:[bp+8]
   push word ptr ss:[bp+0AH]
   mov ax, word ptr ss:[bp+4]
   dec ax
   push ax
   call solve

   pop bp
   ret 8
down:
   pop bp
   ret 8

solve endp

print proc
   push bp
   mov bp, sp
   mov d1, '0'
   mov al, byte ptr ss:[bp+06]
   add d1, al
   mov d2, '0'
   mov al, byte ptr ss:[bp+4]
   add d2, al
   lea dx, text
   mov ah, 09
   int 21h
   pop bp
   ret 4

print endp
end
```

Remember what I said about initialization data? Well, this one has it! Maybe that's why it works.

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! What I don't understand:
Why do you have to return 8 and 4, and what is this line in print:
mov ah, 09

Comment: `RET n` doesn't return `n`; it pops `n` bytes off the stack while returning. The `mov ah,09h` is part of the setup for the `int 21h`. `int 21h` is an interrupt used in DOS programs, and subfunction 9 is _WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT_.